# SQL code for SUM AND MAX

Tags: sql

I have the following table, and want to write a SQL statement to summarize every Article and Extract Maximum?  :

```
| A | 3 |
| B | 6 |
| A | 4 |
```

Output: A=7, B=6.

Comment: will need more info -- what have you tried ?

Comment: @eebbesen: your edit was invalid. Refrain from vandalizing others' posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this;

```
SELECT Article, SUM(Num_Column)
FROM Table_Name
GROUP BY Article
ORDER BY Article
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select columnname,sum(columnname),max(expression/columnname)
from tablename 
group by columnname
```